# Which version of Android should I use when developing Android applications?

Tags: android

Should I use the latest 4.0 or 2.3? My phone has android 2.3.5 and it's a HTC Desire HD. 
Does the runtime matter or will the applications work still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should choose what device versions you'd like to target: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Based on those numbers it makes sense to currently support Android 2.1 and higher.

Also you should read about [`<uses-sdk>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) directive:

`android:minSdkVersion` and `maxSdkVersion` define the version range to which your app will be available. If device has Android version out of this range then app will not be visible for it.

`targetSdkVersion` is the vesrion that you are targeting and that you actually tested against. This attribute triggers Android's compatibility behavior: for instance targeting 2.3 will not show the new look on 4.0 devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think this url will be helpful :
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

All versions of android are backward compatible which means that an application designed to work with 2.0's api will work on 4.0 so it basically comes down to whats your target customers. there's still a vast majority that uses 2.x (unfortunately) so it is probably smart to develop for 2.1 and up..

but anyway this is a pretty common question and i'm sure google will produce a lot of useful information in the subject.